# Difference in probabilities of order $o(1)$

Tags: probability, probability-theory

Let $X_n, Y_n$ be random variables which satisfy $|X_n-Y_n|\leq C$ for some constant $C$.
Let $f:\mathbb{N}\to\mathbb{R}$ satisfy $f(n)\to \infty$ for $n\to\infty$. Is the following equality true?
$$\Pr\left\{|X_n|>f(n)\right\}=\Pr\left\{|Y_n|>f(n)\right\}+o(1).$$

If so, how to show it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, since we could have $X_n$ concentrated about $n-1$, $Y_n$ concentrated about $n+1$, and $f(n)=n$.

Comment: More concretely, $X_n:=n+1$, $Y_n:=n-1$, and $f(n)=n$ satisfy the assumptions and $P(|X_n|>f(n))=1, P(|Y_n|>f(n))=0$. Moreover, it's hard to see a meaningful way to fix the conjecture: if you add the assumption that the random variables are uniformly bounded as $n\to \infty$ in some sense, then the result is trivially true because both probabilities converge to zero, and if you don't, the limit $n\to \infty$ is meaningless